# javascriptでバックグラウンド対応アプリを作れますか？

Tags: javascript, monaca

monacaを使って目覚ましアプリを開発しようと思っているのですが、monacaはバックグラウンド動作は非対応だそうです。
調べたところ、codovaプラグインを使えば出来るみたいですが、js初級者には困難ですか？
また、titaniumとかならできたりするのかなと思ったりするのですが、javascriptでバックグラウンドアプリを作るサービス（IDEなど）が他にあれば教えて頂きたいです。

後、色々な都合でJSでやろうと思ってますが、素直にjavaとか使ったほうが実は楽だったりしますかね…

ちなみにAndroidアプリとして考えてます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9239300.html

Answer (score 0):

Titaniumでは、

Titanium.Android.Intent
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent

を使えばできますよ。
もちろんiOSでも可能です。
http://mobiletou.ch/2014/02/sdk-3-2-1%E7%99%BB%E5%A0%B4%E3%80%81ios7%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E5%BE%8C